# Unable to automate a click to a dropdown box using Selenium IDE 2.9.0

Tags: selenium

I am trying to automate a drop-down box on a site but I can't get Selenium to automatically click the box. I've tried targeting all of the elements within this box and none work.

Can anybody please shed some light?

Many thanks

Comment: I'm not going to ask why you're automating a life insurance policy request form (unless you work there -- and why would you list the name of a site you maintain?). However, could you please post some code for us to poke through? We probably won't be able to solve the problem by guessing.

Comment: A bit more specifics on what you have tried would help.  If sending a `.click()` isn't working to select the item, try a click on the dropdown, followed by `.sendkeys()` with the appropriate number of down arrows then return.

Comment: Fair comment, naivity on my part so I've edited my original post. I was using the .click() function but I will try the other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code to select your required option i.e., **Level Term & Critical Illness** from the Drop down:

```
    //first click on DropDown to open drop down options
    WebElement dropDown = driver.findElement(By
            .xpath(".//*[@id='QuoteAmend_PolicyType_chzn']/a"));
    dropDown.click();

    //Select second option from the drop down
    driver.findElement(
            By.xpath(".//*[@id='QuoteAmend_PolicyType_chzn_o_1']"))
            .click();
```